# python class design: directly use member vars in methods or pass member vars to methods?

Tags: python, design-patterns

Just curious, what are the pros and cons of the following patterns?

pattern 1

```
class Myclass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.val = "foo"
        self.process()
    def process(self):
        #do_sth on self.val
```

pattern 2

```
class Myclass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.val = "foo"
        self.process(self.val)
    def process(self, val):
        #do_sth on val
```

Which one is preferable, and why?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, pattern 1: the purpose of having instance attributes collected together as attributes of one object is so they are collectively passed to functions by passing one object.  And so that setting (or resetting) the value sets (or resets) it for all methods that use it.

On the other hand, pattern 2 allows users to call `process` with other values.

On the third hand, if `process` does not use any self.x values, then there is no reason to pass it `self` and it probably should be a standalone function and not a `MyClass` method.  Or if `val` is never accessed as `self.val`, then it should not be an instance variable.

A class should be a collection of values and functions that belong together because they implement a concept or model a real-world set of objects.

Answer (score 0):

The second "**pattern 2**" is redundant because it implies passing and accessing an argument `self.val` when it's already an instance attribute.
 No need to pass the instance's *local* attribute as an argument to the internal method - it's accessible in any place within a class.
Of course, it's only for those cases when `process` method should deal only with a current instance's attributes